# Real light visualization (math related)

Tags: c++, math

I do have a problem of real lights visualization(in application). Current visualization looks like:

[image]

and what it does is - if light brightness is low - only middle of the ellipse is full brightness, and that is the way of better visualizing a low light situations while still seeing light color, etc.

Used formula:

```
current_ellipse_count = 15; // draw 15 ellipses from small to big one.
brightness = 100; // range is 0 to 255 ! lets say its 'white' light only, so r,g,b are equal.

while (current_ellipse_count > 0) {
    //DRAW small-to-big ELLIPSE AND FILL IT WITH ellipse_brightness. first drawn ellipse is small, and highest current_ellipse_count. so highest amplifying effect of brightness.
    ellipse_brightness = brightness*current_ellipse_count; // so the last ellipse will be real brightness(the biggest one) and the smallest one is always amplified by 15, bigger by 14, etc till the last one is amplified by 1. 
    if (ellipse_brightness > 255) ellipse_brightness = 255; // if it peaks its full brightness then.
    current_ellipse_count--;
}
```

This is simplified way of what i am doing

This way succesfully visualizes low lights situations but in high brightness value, lets say 200 (out of 0-255 range) only the last, biggest, 1 pixel border of the ellipse shows that light is not fully bright.

I need a better formula to correctly show low lights situations and high brightness situations should be lowered.
I think i need a formula which lowers given brightness value, somehow for it to affect it from the half way 125 (out of 0-255 range) up to 255 range, or better - update whole brightness apmlifying affect.

Comment: In the real world light intensity falls off at an `1/(radius*radius)` rate.

Comment: Thanks, i will try to adapt your given formula in near future and will see what i will get from that. But i dont need exact the real world situations, i just need to give user an idea about application output(which is 0-255 for one color).

Comment: @Cornstalks Exactly the same thing I was about to say.

Comment: If you're concerned with the perception of brightness throw in a logarithm.  Check out *Fechner's Law*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ways I can think which might work well:

```
1: ellipse_brightness = (int) (pow(brightness, 0.5) * current_ellipse_count * 2);
```

This should give you better visualization at the high brightness levels. You can adjust the power (0.5) and factor (2) to suit your needs.

```
2: ellipse_brightness = (int) (brightness * 200 / pow(16 - current_ellipse_count, 2));
```

This uses the inverse square law which should give you a similar effect by changing the existing linear falloff. Adjust the constant factor (200) and the power (2) as needed.

You can combine these two for a possibly better effect (through trial and error I found squaring the brightness seems to look better):

```
3: ellipse_brightness = (int) (pow(brightness, 2) * 0.75 / pow(16 - current_ellipse_count, 2));
   if (ellipse_brightness > brightness*4) ellipse_brightness = brightness*4;
```

Finally, @Furkan's answer gave me an idea to use `cos()`:

```
4: ellipse_brightness = (int) (brightness * cos((16 - current_ellipse_count)/15*3.1415926/2) * 2);
```

The output from all these methods looks like the following image (original, #1-4 from top to bottom, left to right is brightness from 0-255 in steps of 16):

[image]

You can play with the parameters of all the methods to adjust things a little, or combine multiple methods as desired.

Comment: Ugh. `pow(..., 0.5)` and `pow(..., 2)`. Why not just use `sqrt` for `0.5`, and squaring with `*`? `pow` is not the most efficient or accurate function... I know graphics is full of approximation hacks, but if the OP is going for "real light visualization" then it makes sense to use the right values.

Comment: Because then you can easily adjust them to use any power. This isn't an attempt to be realistic but to simply get something that looks good.

Comment: Nice, i might get what i want from this. Since Furkan answer is too far from my current abilities to code in c++. Thanks, i ment. I will accept your answer a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for diffuse and specular shading also intensity as `1/(radius*radius)`. I modified it as `1/(4 * pi * radius * radius)`. You can experiment on it as long as the image looks fine.

You can google diffuse and specular shading. There are lots of sources.

```
// Diffuse Shading (Lambertian)
            RGB diffuse;
            float cosineAlpha = objectNormal.dot(lightVector);
            cosineAlpha = abs(cosineAlpha);
            if(cosineAlpha > 0)
            {
                diffuse.r = intensity.r * cosineAlpha * objects[closestObjectId]->matProperty.diffuse.r;
                diffuse.g = intensity.g * cosineAlpha * objects[closestObjectId]->matProperty.diffuse.g;
                diffuse.b = intensity.b * cosineAlpha * objects[closestObjectId]->matProperty.diffuse.b;

                objectColor.r += diffuse.r;
                objectColor.g += diffuse.g;
                objectColor.b += diffuse.b;
            }

// Specular Shading (Blinn-Phong)
            RGB specular;
            Vector3 halfVector;
            halfVector.setX((lightVector + v).x() / ((lightVector + v).length()));
            halfVector.setY((lightVector + v).y() / ((lightVector + v).length()));
            halfVector.setZ((lightVector + v).z() / ((lightVector + v).length()));
            float cosineTeta = objectNormal.dot(halfVector);   
            cosineTeta = abs(cosineTeta); 
            if(cosineTeta > 0)
            {
                float coeff = pow(cosineTeta, objects[closestObjectId]->matProperty.specExp);
                specular.r = intensity.r * coeff * objects[closestObjectId]->matProperty.specular.r;
                specular.g = intensity.g * coeff * objects[closestObjectId]->matProperty.specular.g;
                specular.b = intensity.b * coeff * objects[closestObjectId]->matProperty.specular.b;

                objectColor.r += specular.r;
                objectColor.g += specular.g;
                objectColor.b += specular.b;                        
            }
```

Comment: You can find university documents about diffuse and specular shading. Are you writing from scratch and which algortihm are you using

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is too far from my current knowledge, that is my first c++ application. Still, i will invest some time into analyzing "diffuse and specular shading" in near future. And yes i am writing simple pimple c++ from scratch(current lights visualization works threw drawing ellipses). Learning c++.